# Underline function not working in MiKTeX?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, bibtex, miktex

This seems ridiculous but I'm using LaTeX for the first time in a while and when I attempt to underline like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
\subsection{}
\underline{ActorName} | Phone, Address, AgentName, Appears-In_Scene
\break
...
\end{document}
```

I get a math mode error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.15 ...me} Phone, Address, AgentName, Appears-In_
                                                  Scene
```

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it? I am not opening a math statement anywhere. Also using BibTeX but I don't think that matters.

Comment: In the future, please make sure your code is (besides the problem you are asking about) compilable. For example don't add `...` in the preamble which will cause and error and if you must have `\maketitle` in your code, you also give and `\title{...}` and `\author{...}` so we can concentrate on your actual question and don't have to fix all this unnecessary stuff before actually starting to work on your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not opening a math statement anywhere.

Well, that's the problem. You use a `_` which is a command which must only be used in math mode to write underscores. If you want to write a _, you can use `\textunderscore` or escape the underscore with `\_`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\title{text}
\author{names}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
\subsection{}
\underline{ActorName} | Phone, Address, AgentName, Appears-In\textunderscore Scene
\break
...
\end{document}
```